# When true, does Scala exists stop at the first element that satisfies the predicate?

Tags: scala

My gut feeling is that of course it should and of course it does. But how do I actually check? The computer is so fast that I wouldn't notice a difference of a few milliseconds. For example:

```
(2 to Math.floor(Math.sqrt(121330189)).toInt).exists(121330189 % _ == 0)
```

Locally, it gives the answer immediately. Over Scastie, most of the delay is due to the Internet connection.

Would this stop on 101 or 109 or would it go through the rest?

Comment: Try `exists { x => println(x); predicate(x) }`

Answer (score 5):

It stops early, see for example https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L958.

You could test on a small range by adding some instrumentation (a print) to the predicte function to determine how many times it is called.